# Using regex to select between two tags?

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

Sorry guys for my newbie question

In dreamweaver i want to search and replace between two html tags

```
</title> to <div class="content richcontent">
```

I also searched this site but similar questions don't work with my situation

Thanks in advance

Comment: add at least some sample text which you want to find/replace. Anyway, it looks like you want Dreameweaver to create the regex for you? I am afraid that's not possible

Comment: @Tudor Constantin , no i want to select between </title> and a div like this <div class="content richcontent"> ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Dreamweaver supports regex search and replace you could use this

```
\>(.+)\<
```

I cant remember if it does/did its been many many years since ive used it.

EDIT

Quick google tells me it does! http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/regular_expressions_pt2.html

That link also describes how to use regex for search and replace, as well as just search

Comment: @echolab, your welcome, dont forget to mark the question answered ;)

Answer (score 0):

To output all the text from file called "test.txt" between "FOO" and "BAR", type the following command at a shell prompt. The -n option suppress automatic printing of pattern space:

```
sed -n '/FOO/,/BAR/p' test.txt
```

Comment: How can i do this inside dreamweaver !?